# Set friend ID's in an apprequest using FB.ui?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook JS SDK(FB.ui), is it possible to supply a list of facebook user id's using the 'apprequest' method?

Looking at the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) I see you can set "to:", however I am not sure if this allows you to send a json array of user id's or not. Any help is appreciated!

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    to:[list of ids?], 
    message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', 
    data: 'tracking information for the user'
});
```

I either need to send it to a specific list users or have the boxes prechecked in friend selector if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to try it?
You can always do

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',to:4, message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',to:5, message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',to:6, message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});
```

Comment: Ah good idea! If a user selects lets say 30 friends, will facebook throttle multiple requests?

Comment: I tried to do a loop and run a request per id, and it seems after one it just fails. I'm thinking its because my loop is just a for loop and it is moving on to the next item before the user finishes the first request. Is there a good way to delay a for while the inner code is being confirmed by the user? Or is there a way to stop the loop then continue after the response is sent back?

Answer (score 1):

You could supply the filters parameter which will allow you to have custom lists of users. They wouldn't be pre-selected but you can limit it so that the only friends that show up are the ones you care about.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'Try this out!', filters: [{name: 'friends to invite', user_ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, data: 'tracking data'});
```

Comment: Ah, great idea. The only problem I see is that I have the users already selecting in a multi select their friends they want to notify. When they click submit, I want the user to only have to select their friends one time.